# Two axis ternary system. Projection from x to y, f(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, plot, graph

[image: Wanted result. Partially manually generated in Geogebra]

How can I generate two axes (x,y) at 60deg, and have lines from x to y, with the y points being generated via a function f(x) like regular ?

It would be great, for instance, if the axes could be put in "layers" and the layers tilted to any desired angle, while rays parallel to the axes are generated to make the non-interactive grid (similar to what I did in Geogebra), though it wouldn't hurt if it could be made interactive (as is done in Geo. when the intersection points are added manually, which is depicted).

I'm a noob, have mercy.

btw I'm placing no restriction on the number of axes, or their relative position. I realize a third set of parallel rays would also have to be generated to get the picture, but that "layer" wouldn't have to be interactive at all, since all intersections are gained through the other two.

Answer (score 0):

The code below contains a link to wikipedia for the function

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Sun Oct  6 17:33:00 2019

    @author: thomas

    Ternary Plots, 
    compare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot
    """

    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    def cartesianCoord(tple):
        a,b =tple
        c=1-a-b       #the sum of all ternary coords needs to be 1
        assert (0 <= (a+b) <= 1 ), 'Sum of variables needs to be between 0 and 1'
        return (1/2*(2*b+c)/(a+b+c), math.sqrt(3)/2*c/(a+b+c)) #see wikipedia

    print(cartesianCoord((0.,0.)))

    aa = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)
    bb = np.linspace(0.0, 1.1, 12) #one step more   (see line 30)

    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i,a in enumerate(aa): 
        for b in bb[:-(i+1)]:
            xx,yy = cartesianCoord((a,b))
            x.append(xx)
            y.append(yy)
    plt.scatter(x,y)  #scatter points for the coordination system grid

    tlines = [((0.8, 0.0), (0.0, 0.7)), ((0.0, 0.2), (0.4, 0.4)), ((0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0))] #ternary
    for l in tlines:
        a = cartesianCoord(l[0]) #start
        e = cartesianCoord(l[1]) #end
        x = [a[0], e[0]]
        y = [a[1], e[1]]
        plt.plot(x,y , color='red')  #plot the lines in red

    plt.show()
```

Comment: As a total noob, I can't tell if the script is doing what I described, by reading it.  But the general idea is to move away from the cartesian coordinate system, at least on the surface level of the code itself.